# JavaFX WebView slash code is converted

Tags: javascript, java, webview

javascript

```
function test(testVar){
    //testVar: C:&#92;helloworld.txt
    var myDIV = document.getElementById('myDIV');
    myDIV.innerHTML = "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"app.test('" + testVar + "')\">test</a>"
}
```

java webview application code

```
public void test(final String testVar){
    System.out.println(testVar);
    //supposed to print C:&#92;helloworld.txt, but prints C:helloworld.txt
}
```

This thing is bothering me. The slash "\" in testVar is not interpreted as a character, but as a special character thing (I don't know the term) that for example denotes "\n" for next line, "\t" for tab and "\r" for return.

So, I changed it to the HTML code `&#92;` before executing the Javascript. However, when I click on the link, the same thing occurs, the slash is not treated as a character and basically screws up the String.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Backslash in java is a escape character, use it followed by another backslash to insert one.

```
"\\" prints "\"
```

Just like `\n` prints a new line.

reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html